# distorted icons on download dialog box

Tags: 18.04, icons

## Summary

Sometimes, when I'm trying to specify the destination of a downloaded file, I face a dialogue box like below, in which the icons for my favourites shortcuts as well as some other look distorted.

[image]

It apparently causes no other harm (although I'm not really knowledgable in this area to distinguish wrong from right).

## UPDATE

This problem is very likely to be caused by Chromium. I checked the same with Firefox and Brave. In both cases the icons are fine. [I have other problems with chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295971/chromium-doesnt-recognize-libreoffice-as-default) too. Although I'm not sure if they are really related.

## More info

Please let me the needed information in the comments. I'm still a newbie in Ubuntu.

- Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Chromium Version 87.0.4280.66 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)

Comment: Try rebuild the cache: `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/; sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/local/share/icons/`

Comment: Thanks, @user.dz ! Unfortunately, it happens only sometimes. I'll update my cache the next time this happened and will inform you about the result.

Comment: @user.dz I couldn't rebuild my cache. I got the following error twice: `gtk-update-icon-cache: No theme index file.`