# [UPDATED]: Chromium doesn't recognize LibreOffice as default

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, chromium

Whenever I download a `.docx` type document, Chromium (my default browser) always asks me about the program by which I want to open the document. Even though LibreOffice is my only and default office like application:

[image]

If I download the file with Firefox or open any `.docx` file from my own computer, LibreOffice opens it, promptly and obediently, with no further questioning.

I know it's literally a "double-click" difference. But sometimes, these frequent interruptions become gradually annoying, especially if you don't know how to fix them. So, can you, the community, share your thoughts with me to fix it forever, please? (btw, I'm very dependent on chrome-based browsers and I cannot switch to any other, in case the comment "change your browser" crossed your mind too)

## UPDATE

This problem seems to be more prevalent than I thought. The same happens with Thunderbird and an email link. Once an email link is clicked in Chromium, it again asks which program to be used, regardless of your default mail client manager.

My very limited knowledge suggests that Chromium can't handle the auto-execution of other programs (related to `xdg-open`?). I hope this sheds some light on the reason behind it. It would be also very nice if someone follows the following procedure to see if (s)he can replicate the issue. **If it also occurs in other machines, then please leave a comment so that I can change the title appropriately.**

## How to replicate the issue

Open Chromium and try to click on an email link or just see what happens after copying the following on your address bar: `mailto:fake@email.com`. If it didn't recognize your default client manager, then there is an issue.